# Dont apply rule when it starts with a particular word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^-]+)-([^&]+)$ lala.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

second rule:

```
RewriteRule ^testpage/([^-]+)-([^&]+)$ lala.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

The first rule overwrites the second rule. Is there a possibility to say smth like: Apply the first rule when ([a-z]+) is not "testpage"?

Comment: the simple way is to put the 2nd rule before the 1st rule, the 'less' simple way is to use rewrite conditions

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the order around so that the more restrictive "testpage" rule gets processed before the more general `([a-z]+)` one is:

```
RewriteRule ^testpage/([^-]+)-([^&]+)$ lala.php?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^-]+)-([^&]+)$ lala.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```